# Generate links without en when target page has no translation

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a page which is partly translated. Default is German, translation is English. Now I have the problem, that all links generated with typolink or menus have an English domain part (www.domain.de/en/pagename) no matter if it is translated or not. When I click on it, I see the German content. The wish is, that if there is no translation of the target page, the link shall generate without the "en". How can I achieve that?

I tried with

```
config.sys_language_mode = default
```

but had no success. The description of this setting sounded like it could be the answer.

I have realurl here and TYPO3 4.6 (I know it should be updated, but not in my hand).

Answer (score 0):

If found the solution myself.
The magic was the property

```
protectLvar = all
```

in the HMENU object. See also description in [tsref https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/4.7/ContentObjects(cobject)/Hmenu/Index.html](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/4.7/ContentObjects(cobject)/Hmenu/Index.html)